# In inSSIDer, what is the difference between WPA2-CCMP and RSNA-CCMP?

Tags: wifi, wpa2

inSSIDer shows my wireless network as RSNA-CCMP.  The settings on the wireless router (Linksys E2000) do not at all seem to suggest an "RSNA" security option.  The security filtering options in inSSIDer have both a WPA2-CCMP and RSNA-CCMP available.

What is the difference between these?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The RSNA-CCMP filter is an accidental left-over from when I wrote the filtering system. It is exactly the same as the WPA2-CCMP filter. :D

Comment: By that, I take it you're the original programmer for inssider? Feel free to point that out :)

Comment: Yes, I wrote most of inSSIDer 2. :)

Answer (score 2):

From what I can gather, for practical purposes these are the same thing, just different name.  RSNA stands for Robust Security Network Assocation, which is part of the 802.11i spec (per [this article on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robust_Security_Network) )

Comment: That's what I figured, but I'm trying to understand why these would be two separate things in inSSIDer.